# How do I simulate an abstract class and call its constructor?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, typescript

I'm trying to follow along with a C# design patterns book by writing my code in TypeScript. Perhaps this is my first mistake, but it's a way I enjoy to learn a language.

TypeScript doesn't support the abstract keyword for classes, so I am trying to simulate it. Maybe this is my second mistake.

Here is my interface and classes:

```
interface IEngine {
  getSize(): number;
  getTurbo(): boolean;
}

class AbstractEngine implements IEngine {
  constructor(private size: number, private turbo: boolean) {
    throw "Abstract class";
  }

  public getSize(): number {
    return this.size;
  }

  public getTurbo(): boolean {
    return this.turbo;
  }

  public toString(): string {
    var funcNameRegex = /function (.{1,})\(/;
    var results = (funcNameRegex).exec(this.constructor.toString());
    var className = (results && results.length > 1) ? results[1] : '';
    return className + " (" + this.size + ")";
  }
}

class StandardEngine extends AbstractEngine {
  constructor(size: number) {
    // not turbo charged
    super(size, false);
  }
}
```

When trying to instantiate an AbstractEngine with `new AbstractEngine(1, true)` I get an "Abstract class" error as expected.

When trying to instantiate a StandardEngine with `new StandardEngine(9000)` I also get an "Abstract class" error.

Is there a way I can simulate an abstract class in TypeScript, have it unable to be instantiated, but still call super in a class that extends it? And what about simulating abstract methods, can I protect those and still call the super method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I advise you not to do that. When the TypeScript compiler will implement a mechanism for abstract function, it is time to use it. But hacks that work at runtime are incomprehensible and degrade performance.

The interfaces are the great strength of TypeScript. They should be used massively.

Your example should be written like this:

```
interface Engine {
  getSize(): number;
  getTurbo(): boolean;
}

class StandardEngine implements Engine {
  constructor(private size: number, private turbo: boolean) {
  }
  public getSize(): number {
    return this.size;
  }
  public getTurbo(): boolean {
    return this.turbo;
  }
}
```

The simplest solution is often the best.

If you want to reuse code without a parent class which would then necessarily usable, the [Handbook suggests Mixins](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#mixins). Mixins are a way of coping skills from several distinct entities.

Or with modules it is possible to keep private implementation (and therefore organize it as you want it) and export only interfaces and factories. An example:

```
module MyEngineModule {
  export interface Engine {
    getSize(): number;
    getTurbo(): boolean;
  }
  export interface StandardEngine extends Engine {
  }
  export function makeStandardEngine(size: number, turbo: boolean): StandardEngine {
    return new ImplStandardEngine(size, turbo);
  }
  // here classes are private and can inherit or use mixins…
  class ImplEngine {
    constructor(private size: number, private turbo: boolean) {
    }
    public getSize(): number {
      return this.size;
    }
    public getTurbo(): boolean {
      return this.turbo;
    }
  }
  class ImplStandardEngine extends ImplEngine implements StandardEngine {
  }
}
console.log(MyEngineModule.makeStandardEngine(123, true).getSize());
```

Comment: But I need to be able to share the implementation in AbstractEngine across several different concrete classes, not just StandardEngine. Sorry that I didn't make that obvious in my post. I don't see how your solution helps accomplish that. *edit* Ahh, nevermind, I see your mentioning the part about mixins that would accomplish sharing the code across multiple concrete classes. I'll have to give it a try.

Comment: After implementing this using mixins, I'm a little disappointed at how much code I had to copy to both the StandardEngine and TurboEngine classes. I wish there was a keyword that took care of this and removed the necessity of calling applyMixins, or abstract classes, or both.

Comment: Also, the custom toString method on Engine always prints "Engine" for the class name when implemented as a mixin instead of "StandardEngine" or "TurboEngine" like it did when using inheritance.

Comment: I agree, mixins lack elegance. They are a manual manipulations in prototypes, and it is not DRY.

I suggest you to use the last solution. In a module, make private classes with inheritance. For example ImplEngine ← ImplStandardEngine. From outside of the module, ImplEngine will not be instanciated.

Answer (score 5):

As of today, [TypeScript 1.6 is live](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2015/09/16/announcing-typescript-1-6.aspx) and has support for the `abstract` keyword.

```
abstract class A {
  foo(): number { return this.bar(); }
  abstract bar(): number;
}

var a = new A();  // error, Cannot create an instance of the abstract class 'A'

class B extends A {
  bar() { return 1; }
}

var b = new b();  // success, all abstracts are defined
```

Answer (score 0):

When calling the `StandardEngine constructor`, you have a call to `super(size, false)`.  This call into the base class is what is generating the second "Abstract class" error.

To simulate an abstract base class that will throw when instantiated, create an Init function that is called from your derived class.

```
class AbstractEngine implements IEngine {
  private _size: number;
  private _turbo: boolean;
  constructor() {
    throw "Abstract class";
  }
  init(size:number, turbo: boolean) {
    this._size = size;
    this._turbo = turbo;
  }
}

class StandardEngine extends AbstractEngine {
  constructor(size: number) {
    // not turbo charged
    // do not call super here
    init(size, false);
  }
}
```

Comment: If I omit the call to super in StandardEngine I get the error "Constructors for derived classes must contain a 'super' call". When trying your code out I also get the error "Could not find symbol 'init'" because it's missing the "this" qualifier.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution would be to user a property that if set indicates that the constructor is being called from a child class it is safe to continue. This is shown below :

```
class AbstractEngine {
  safe; // IMPORTANT : do not initialize
  constructor(private size: number, private turbo: boolean) {
    if(!this.safe) throw "Abstract class"; // IMPORTANT
  }    

}

class StandardEngine extends AbstractEngine {  
  constructor(size: number) {       
    this.safe = true; // IMPORTANT
    super(size, false);
  }
}
```

Comment: When I tried this code out, I still got the error thrown for Abstract class when instantiating a StandardEngine. I understand the idea, but the implementation doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @brycedarling I fixed the error. the base class should not set the value otherwise the child value will get overwritten :)